# Sorting 2d array in java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, 2d, comparator

I'm learning java and trying out UVA questions. This is UVA 612.
I've used the Comparator to sort my String array but i have no idea why the value 9 is larger than all the number. This is my code:

```
    public static String getSort(String str) {
    int SLEN = str.length();
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < SLEN; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j < SLEN; j++) {
            if (str.charAt(i) > str.charAt(j)) {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return Integer.toString(count);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int SLEN = sc.nextInt();
    int LINE = sc.nextInt();
    String[][] table = new String[LINE][2];
    for (int i = 0; i < LINE; i++) {
        table[i][1] = sc.next();
        table[i][0] = getSort(table[i][1]);
    }

    Arrays.sort(table, new Comparator<String[]>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(final String[] entry1, final String[] entry2) {
            final String str1 = entry1[0];
            final String str2 = entry2[0];
            return str1.compareTo(str2);
        }
    });

    for (int i = 0; i < LINE; i++) {
        System.out.println(table[i][1]);
    }

    sc.close();
}
```

The input is:

```
10 6
AACATGAAGG
TTTTGGCCAA
TTTGGCCAAA
GATCAGATTT
CCCGGGGGGA
ATCGATGCAT
```

Output I got is:

```
AACATGAAGG #10
GATCAGATTT #11
ATCGATGCAT #17
TTTTGGCCAA #36
TTTGGCCAAA #37
CCCGGGGGGA #9
```

But the expected output is:

```
CCCGGGGGGA #9
AACATGAAGG #10
GATCAGATTT #11
ATCGATGCAT #17
TTTTGGCCAA #36
TTTGGCCAAA #37
```

The integer behind hash is the value of getSort(). I have no idea why the value 9 is the largest after sorting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sorting the array alphabetically but it seems that you want to sort it numerically. Try this:

```
Arrays.sort(table, new Comparator<String[]>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(final String[] entry1, final String[] entry2) {
            int n1 = Integer.parseInt(entry1[0]);
            int n2 = Integer.parseInt(entry2[0]);
            return n1 - n2;
        }
    });
```